# How to disable collider2D when another gameobject is on top of it

Tags: unity, c#

Each black colored square has a `BoxCollider2D`. How can I disable the collider after I put another game object on top of it?

Here is the sample output:

[image: my sample output]

Comment: what do you mean by "on top of it"? do you mean it *has* to align with the object, first? Does it have to be perfect, or would it be more suitable to detect when the objects are first *touching*, before *manually* aligning the second object to be "on top"?

Comment: When I drag a game object and hit the square, it changes position base on the collider position. I want to disable the colliders occupied by the game object.

Comment: So when your object hits the square (i.e. when there is any collision between "object" and "square"), you want to disable the collider attached to "object"?

Comment: I want to disable the collider of the square

Comment: Why are you not using `Trigger`? or something like your "square" has no `Trigger` and "object" has, when it collides then make `Trigger` enable to "square" and disable in "object"?

Comment: @Hamza Hasan, what do you mean? Your comment is very rough, and hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: most of what I discuss, below, is general to collision. While you can reference a 2D collider as a generic `Collider`, most other actions require *direct* reference to the *type* of collider you are using, more specifically whether it is for 2D or 3D. This includes the function call, and assurance that you are using the correct `Rigidbody`|`Rigidbody2D` and `Physics`|`Physics2D`, where applicable.**

Colliders are a separate component, even when attached to a game object, so disabling them on collision is actually quite easy.

To disable the collider from a script attached to the same object, you can simply use

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
}
```

This is the same as creating a reference to the collider on the other game object with `Collider collider = GetComponent<Collider>()` and disabling it with `collider.SetActive(false)`, but quicker, given that we do not need to use the reference `collider` after we initially disable it.

If your script is on the *other* object, we only need to accommodate the fact that we are looking for the collider on the *other* object with `collision.other.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>()`.

If your script ends up invoking `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)`, instead, you can reference the *other* collider directly with `other`, or access the `GameObject` with `other.gameObject`. Note that `OnTrigger` functions directly pass a `Collider`, as these instances only need to work with *what* was hit, and does not need the extra information passed through a `Collision` object.

#### `Collider` is compatible with all types of colliders

Note that `Collider` is an object that represents colliders, and as such, all colliders inherit from it. That means that this reference will work regardless of whether you are using a `BoxCollider`, a `BoxCollider2D`, a `MeshCollider` or any other variation that suits your particular needs.

#### Handling multiple colliders on the same game object

When things get more complicated, your game object may contain several colliders<sup>1</sup>. You can use `GetComponents<Collider>` to return a list of *all* colliders on the game object, and iterate through them to disable each one.

#### Use tags to identify what it is your hitting

You may find that there are certain situations where your object collides with another object, but not the object you wish to trigger the 'disable collider' logic on. [You can set tags on objects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html), and check if `other.tag` matches the same tag you use on the objects you intend to trigger the specific action. In the case where only the "square" should cause the collider to disable, you would ensure the object correctly has the "square" tag, and use `if(other.tag == "square"){}` to encase your `collider.enabled = false` code.

<sub><sup>1</sup> While you can only have one `Collider` component on a single `GameObject`, you may have children attached to your game object that also contain colliders.</sub>

Comment: I'm making a drag and drop program where i want to drag object to specific area.

Comment: its `Collider2D` bro :D

Comment: I could edit your answer, but it is too long actually.. :P

Comment: so many things left

Comment: @HamzaHasan, if you think there is more to add, you should post it as your own answer.

Comment: I'm sorry bro if I hit you, but it is my duty to point out visible mistakes in answers, like you did change `OnCollisionEnter` to `OnCollisionEnter2D` but didn't change its parameters, that should be `Collision2D` and a long list...

Comment: @HamzaHasan, I don't know what to tell you. I tested it all out in a test environment Ive previously built for 3D, missed the direct reference as copying it across was quicker. If you think you have a better answer, you should post it. If we can have a better quality answer to the question, all the better. Its certainly more constructive than just trying to insist that you *could* post a better answer.